# Create A New Image() Object Inside A Template Literal - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, image, object, template-literals

I have an JavaScript image previewer that shows image files before they are processed in PHP. The previewer currently appends a new `Image()` object inside an `<article>` element, which itself is appended to a parent container.

I would like to add a couple of other elements to the HTML in addition to what is done below and instead of creating and appending them all with `createElement()` and `append()` I wondered if this is possible with template literals (template strings)?

Here is the original code:

```
function updateThumbnail(file) {
    
    if (file.type.startsWith("image/")) {

        const uploadImageWrapper = document.createElement('article')

        const thumbnailElement = new Image();

        thumbnailElement.classList.add("drop-zone__thumb");
        thumbnailElement.src = URL.createObjectURL(file);

        showSelectedImages.append(uploadImageWrapper)
        uploadImageWrapper.append(thumbnailElement);
    }

} // end of 'updateThumbnail' function
```

And here is an attempt to do it with template stings:

```
// updateThumbnail function that needs to be able to handle multiple files
function updateThumbnail(file) {
    
    if (file.type.startsWith("image/")) {

        const uploadImageWrapper = document.createElement('article')

        const thumbnailElement = new Image();

        showSelectedImages.innerHTML = 
        `
        <article>
        ${thumbnailElement}
        </article>
        `

        thumbnailElement.classList.add("drop-zone__thumb");
        thumbnailElement.src = URL.createObjectURL(file);

    }

} // end of 'updateThumbnail' function
```

I don't get any errors showing in the console, but instead of the thumbnailElement showing I get `[object HTMLImageElement]` printed to the screen.

Is it possible to instantiate a new `Image()` object inside a template literal?

Comment: The short answer is "No". You can do it with [`XMLSerializer.serializeToString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLSerializer/serializeToString), but when you stringify it like that, the variable no longer references the serialized element. You'll be better off using methods like [`Element.insertAdjacentElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentElement) and [`Element.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector).

Comment: @jsejcksn Thank you.